# What does 'sun bar' mean in the noun phrase 'Aztec sun bar bracelet'?

Tags: meaning

What does 'sun bar' mean in the noun phrase 'Aztec sun bar bracelet'? Does it have anything to do with Sun?

Comment: It's not (Aztec) (sun bar), it's (Aztec sun) (bar). It's meant to resemble a symbol for the Sun, for example on the flag of New Mexico.

Comment: Hi! I appreciate you accepting my answer, but I also think The Photon and Mark Beadles nailed it with the New Mexico flag theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a fairly arbitrary name for a particular way of weaving or knotting cord to form a bracelet.

[image]

([image source](http://www.free-macrame-patterns.com/aztec-sun-bar.html))

Per [this page](http://www.free-macrame-patterns.com/macrame-terms.html), *bar* is a term referring to a wide, flat macrame design.

The name may be inspired by the similarity of the pattern to something like the sun symbol found on the New Mexico state flag

[image]

([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg))

However the New Mexico flag was inspired by a [Zia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zia_people) symbol rather than an Aztec one.

Answer (score 1):

"Bar" here appears to be a specialized term used by paracord tie/bracelet hobbyists. Quoting "[Paracord Fusion Ties Vol. 1](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Paracord_Fusion_Ties.html?id=0PCYW9-0h_4C&redir_esc=y)" by J.D. Lenzen:

> Bar: A semi-ridged, tightly constructed, tie typically made with square knots (e.g.
>   Solomon Bar).

Considering the abundance of other "Bars" with exotic names described in the book such as "Crooked River Bar", "Tiki Bar" and "Long Dragon Bar", it's possible it was named a "sun bar" due to certain resemblance with the Aztec sun motive:

[image]